# T4240RDB-64B - QoIQ SDK 2.0 - Kernel crashes

Tags: linux

I built T4240rdb-64b with QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto on Ubuntu Linux 16. LTS 64bit.
This is my commands to build it:

```
~/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto$ source ./fsl-setup-env -m t4240rdb-64b
Configuring for t4240rdb-64b ...
~/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_t4240rdb-64b was created before.
Back to build project ~/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_t4240rdb-64b.
Nothing is changed.
~/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_t4240rdb-64b$ bitbake fsl-image-minimal
WARNING: Host distribution "Ubuntu-16.04" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
Loading cache: 100% |##########################################################################################################| ETA: 00:00:00
Loaded 6050 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION = "1.28.0"
BUILD_SYS = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING = "Ubuntu-16.04"
TARGET_SYS = "powerpc64-fsl-linux"
MACHINE = "t4240rdb-64b"
DISTRO = "fsl-qoriq"
DISTRO_VERSION = "2.0"
TUNE_FEATURES = "m64 fpu-hard e6500 altivec"
TARGET_FPU = "hard"
meta 
meta-yocto 
meta-yocto-bsp = "HEAD:9a211a4a2c1bfcb292dc97d8dcac149bca9e3f1b"
meta-oe 
meta-multimedia 
meta-gnome 
meta-networking 
meta-perl 
meta-python 
meta-ruby 
meta-filesystems 
meta-webserver 
meta-xfce = "HEAD:dc5634968b270dde250690609f0015f881db81f2"
meta-freescale = "HEAD:7facbdb726e2dda0515e084c2066a4b8dd99c6d2"
meta-freescale-internal = "HEAD:4829293f807e35a1111e79763294fc8b98b97810"
meta-freescale-extra = "HEAD:bee911b027e0480b034674d0ddee3fcb06d2e985"
meta-virtualization = "HEAD:042425c1d98bdd7e44a62789bd03b375045266f5"
meta-java = "HEAD:8b776ac68f9af4596be3824152bcf0bc6b67fa1d"
meta-openstack 
meta-openstack-aio-deploy 
meta-openstack-compute-deploy 
meta-openstack-compute-test-config 
meta-openstack-controller-deploy 
meta-openstack-controller-test-config 
meta-openstack-qemu 
meta-openstack-swift-deploy 
meta-cloud-services = "HEAD:d8bc0d92d0f741e2ea1e6d3d9bc6b7a091d03cfb"
meta-security = "HEAD:f9367e71f923fc7d2fb600208e2b97535ea41777"
NOTE: Preparing RunQueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1499 tasks of which 1499 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown.
~/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_t4240rdb-64b$
```

When I run QEMU with this command:

```
sudo ~/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_t4240rdb-64b/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/qemu-system-ppc64 \
-cpu e5500 -nographic -m 1028 -M ppce500 \
-kernel ~/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_t4240rdb-64b/tmp/deploy/images/t4240rdb-64b/uImage \
-initrd ~/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_t4240rdb-64b/tmp/deploy/images/t4240rdb-64b/fsl-image-minimal-t4240rdb-64b.ext2.gz \
-append "root=/dev/ram rw console=ttyS0,115200 \
ip=26.26.26.2::26.26.26.1:255.255.255.0 mem=1028M" -serial tcp::4444,server,telnet -net nic,model=e1000 \
-net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no
```

It couldn't boot. This is boot massages:

```
~/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/build_t4240rdb-64b$ telnet 26.26.26.1 4444
Trying 26.26.26.1...
Connected to 26.26.26.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Using QEMU e500 machine description
MMU: Supported page sizes
4 KB as direct
4096 KB as direct
16384 KB as direct
65536 KB as direct
262144 KB as direct
1048576 KB as direct
MMU: Book3E HW tablewalk not supported
Found initrd at 0xc000000004000000:0xc000000004423e3b
bootconsole [udbg0] enabled
CPU maps initialized for 1 thread per core
Starting Linux PPC64 #1 SMP Sun Jan 8 12:42:09 ICT 2017
-----------------------------------------------------
ppc64_pft_size = 0x0
phys_mem_size = 0x40000000
dcache_line_size = 0x40
icache_line_size = 0x40
cpu_features = 0x00180400181802c0
possible = 0x00180480581802c8
always = 0x00180400581802c0
cpu_user_features = 0xcc008000 0x08000000
mmu_features = 0x000a0010
firmware_features = 0x0000000000000000
-----------------------------------------------------
<- setup_system()
Linux version 4.1.8-rt8+gbd51baf (hstan@server-06) (gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sun Jan 8 12:42:09 ICT 2017
qemu_e500_setup_arch()
Zone ranges:
DMA [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003fffffff]
DMA32 empty
Normal empty
Movable zone start for each node
Early memory node ranges
node 0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003fffffff]
Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003fffffff]
MMU: Allocated 2112 bytes of context maps for 255 contexts
PERCPU: Embedded 17 pages/cpu @c00000003f000000 s28824 r0 d40808 u1048576
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on. Total pages: 258560
Kernel command line: root=/dev/ram rw console=ttyS0,115200 ip=26.26.26.2::26.26.26.1:255.255.255.0 mem=1028M
PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
Sorting __ex_table...
Memory: 949036K/1048576K available (7856K kernel code, 1132K rwdata, 3008K rodata, 364K init, 764K bss, 99540K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
Hierarchical RCU implementation.
RCU debugfs-based tracing is enabled.
CONFIG_RCU_FANOUT set to non-default value of 32
Additional per-CPU info printed with stalls.
RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=24 to nr_cpu_ids=1.
RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=1
NR_IRQS:512 nr_irqs:512 16
mpic: Setting up MPIC " OpenPIC " version 1.2 at fe0040000, max 1 CPUs
mpic: ISU size: 256, shift: 8, mask: ff
mpic: Initializing for 256 sources
clocksource timebase: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x5c4093a7d1, max_idle_ns: 440795210635 ns
clocksource: timebase mult[2800000] shift[24] registered
Console: colour dummy device 80x25
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
e500 family performance monitor hardware support registered
Brought up 1 CPUs
devtmpfs: initialized
clocksource jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
xor: measuring software checksum speed
8regs : 1289.000 MB/sec
8regs_prefetch: 1079.000 MB/sec
32regs : 1745.000 MB/sec
32regs_prefetch: 1572.000 MB/sec
xor: using function: 32regs (1745.000 MB/sec)
NET: Registered protocol family 16
Found FSL PCI host bridge at 0x0000000fe0008000. Firmware bus number: 0->255
PCI host bridge /pci@fe0008000 (primary) ranges:
MEM 0x0000000c00000000..0x0000000c1fffffff -> 0x00000000e0000000 
IO 0x0000000fe1000000..0x0000000fe100ffff -> 0x0000000000000000
/pci@fe0008000: PCICSRBAR @ 0xdff00000
setup_pci_atmu: end of DRAM 40000000
EDAC PCI0: Giving out device to module MPC85xx_edac controller mpc85xx_pci_err: DEV fe0008000.pci (INTERRUPT)
MPC85xx_edac acquired irq 24 for PCI Err
MPC85xx_edac PCI err registered
fsl-pamu: fsl_pamu_init: could not find a PAMU node
PCI: Probing PCI hardware
fsl-pci fe0008000.pci: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io 0x10000-0x1ffff] (bus address [0x0000-0xffff])
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xc00000000-0xc1fffffff] (bus address [0xe0000000-0xffffffff])
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
pci 0000:00:00.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring
pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01-ff]
PCI: Cannot allocate resource region 0 of device 0000:00:00.0, will remap
pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xc00000000-0xc000fffff]
pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 8: assigned [mem 0xc00100000-0xc001fffff]
pci 0000:00:01.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xc00200000-0xc0023ffff pref]
pci 0000:00:01.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xc00240000-0xc0025ffff]
pci 0000:00:01.0: BAR 1: assigned [io 0x11000-0x1103f]
pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
pci 0000:00:00.0: bridge window [io 0x10000-0x10fff]
pci 0000:00:00.0: bridge window [mem 0xc00100000-0xc001fffff]
raid6: int64x1 gen() 721 MB/s
raid6: int64x1 xor() 495 MB/s
raid6: int64x2 gen() 1018 MB/s
raid6: int64x2 xor() 370 MB/s
raid6: int64x4 gen() 1334 MB/s
raid6: int64x4 xor() 890 MB/s
raid6: int64x8 gen() 650 MB/s
raid6: int64x8 xor() 440 MB/s
raid6: using algorithm int64x4 gen() 1334 MB/s
raid6: .... xor() 890 MB/s, rmw enabled
raid6: using intx1 recovery algorithm
vgaarb: loaded
SCSI subsystem initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
PTP clock support registered
EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
No BMan portals available!
QMan: Allocated lookup table at 8000000000002000, entry count 65537
No QMan portals available!
No USDPAA memory, no 'fsl,usdpaa-mem' in device-tree
Switched to clocksource timebase
NET: Registered protocol family 2
TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
NET: Registered protocol family 1
RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
rootfs image is not initramfs (no cpio magic); looks like an initrd
Freeing initrd memory: 4236K (c000000004000000 - c000000004423000)
futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
audit: type=2000 audit(0.952:1): initialized
HugeTLB registered 4 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 16 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 64 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 256 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
HugeTLB registered 1 GB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
Key type id_resolver registered
Key type id_legacy registered
ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O].
jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
async_tx: api initialized (async)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
console [ttyS0] disabled
serial8250.0: ttyS0 at MMIO 0xfe0004500 (irq = 42, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
console [ttyS0] enabled
console [ttyS0] enabled
bootconsole [udbg0] disabled
bootconsole [udbg0] disabled
ePAPR hypervisor byte channel driver
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
st: Version 20101219, fixed bufsize 32768, s/g segs 256
libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
Freescale FM module, FMD API version 21.1.0
Freescale FM Ports module
fsl_mac: fsl_mac: FSL FMan MAC API based driver
fsl_dpa: FSL DPAA Ethernet driver
fsl_advanced: FSL DPAA Advanced drivers:
fsl_proxy: FSL DPAA Proxy initialization driver
fsl_dpa_shared: FSL DPAA Shared Ethernet driver
fsl_dpa_macless: FSL DPAA MACless Ethernet driver
fsl_oh: FSL FMan Offline Parsing port driver
e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.3.2-k
e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2014 Intel Corporation.
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
i2c /dev entries driver
md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
Freescale(R) MPC85xx EDAC driver, (C) 2006 Montavista Software
sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver
No fsl,qman node
Freescale USDPAA process driver
fsl-usdpaa: no region found
Freescale USDPAA process IRQ driver
dce_sys_init done!
No fsl,dce node
Freescale pme2 db driver
PME2: fsl_pme2_db_init: not on ctrl-plane
Freescale pme2 scan driver
fsl-pme2-scan: device pme_scan registered
Freescale hypervisor management driver
fsl-hv: no hypervisor found
ipip: IPv4 over IPv4 tunneling driver
Initializing XFRM netlink socket
NET: Registered protocol family 10
sit: IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
NET: Registered protocol family 17
NET: Registered protocol family 15
8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
Key type dns_resolver registered
fsl_generic: FSL DPAA Generic Ethernet driver
hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
md: Skipping autodetection of RAID arrays. (raid=autodetect will force)
RAMDISK: gzip image found at block 0
VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) on device 1:0.
devtmpfs: mounted
Freeing unused kernel memory: 364K (c000000000aa3000 - c000000000afe000)
init[1]: unhandled signal 4 at 00003fff90c3c0fc nip 00003fff90c3c0fc lr 00003fff90c1dd94 code 30001
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000004
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.1.8-rt8+gbd51baf #1
Call Trace:
[c0000000390538d0] [c0000000007a34fc] .dump_stack+0x8c/0xb8 (unreliable)
[c000000039053950] [c0000000007a0e34] .panic+0xf0/0x270
[c0000000390539f0] [c00000000003b520] .do_exit+0xa00/0xa04
[c000000039053ae0] [c00000000003c5a4] .do_group_exit+0x54/0xec
[c000000039053b70] [c000000000048640] .get_signal+0x2f8/0x674
[c000000039053c70] [c0000000000092bc] .do_signal+0x44/0x218
[c000000039053db0] [c00000000000959c] .do_notify_resume+0x64/0x78
[c000000039053e30] [c000000000000c4c] .ret_from_except_lite+0x78/0x7c
Rebooting in 180 seconds..
```

I've try boot from SD card on real T4240RDB board, it happen the same error.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because the warning:

```
WARNING: Host distribution "Ubuntu-16.04" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
```

I have tryed build on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but the same error when I boot the image and rootfs.